# jquery fancybox + angularJS: fancybox button action issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller, fancybox

I'm curious how to add another button in the fancybox that does something.

[here is the code http://plnkr.co/edit/fHTfBpfHGspOO3BTlgYA?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/fHTfBpfHGspOO3BTlgYA?p=preview) that shows 3 fancyboxes with dynamical content.
However I'm having an issue with buttons - don't know how to make any actions with `ng-click="doSomething()` inside the button as html code for fancybox is generated outside of the controller scope (if I understand it properly) and can't be reached from the original controller.

Here is the code of 4 files:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('appController', ['$scope',
  function ControllerZero($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{
      'name': 'First Item',
      'description': 'first description'
    }, {
      'name': 'Second item',
      'description': 'second description'
    }, {
      'name': 'Third Item',
      'description': 'third description'
    }];
  }
]);

app.directive('fancybox', function ($compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.openFancybox = function (url) {

                    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
                        if (response.status == 200) {

                            var template = angular.element(response.data);
                            var compiledTemplate = $compile(template);
                            compiledTemplate($scope);

                            $.fancybox.open({ content: template, type: 'html' });
                        }
                    });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Fancybox</title>

    <link data-require="fancybox@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.css" />

    <script data-require="jquery@1.8.2" data-semver="1.8.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="fancybox@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appController">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">

        <div class="name">{{ item.name }}</div> 

          <div fancybox ng-click="openFancybox('template.html')" >Click here</div>

        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
/* Put your css in here */

li {list-style-type: none; border: 1px solid #efefef; width:200px; margin-bottom:10px; padding:10px;}
li div {display: inline-block; width:90px; color: grey;}
li div.name {color: black; font-weight: bold;}
```

template.html

```
<h2>{{item.description}}</h2>
<button ng-click="doSomething()">close this fancybox and write something into console</button>
<button>open the fancybox with the Second Item</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update your some code in directives. see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9nAUfFNUIw4msH8UbVV3?p=preview)

Follow this process to bind View with Scope:

```
//create an angular element. (this is our "view")
var element = angular.element(html),

//compile the view into a function.
compiled = $compile(element);

//DOM updation
body.append(element );

//bind our view to the scope!
compiled(scope);
```

So I made changes in your *fancybox* directive,

```
app.directive('fancybox', ['$compile', '$http',
  function($compile, $http) {
    return function($scope) {

      $scope.openFancybox = function(url) {
        $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 200) {

            var template = angular.element(response.data);
            var compiledTemplate = $compile(template);


            $.fancybox.open({
              content: template,
              type: 'html'
            });

           compiledTemplate($scope);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

And also add *doSomething()* function in your controller scope

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
 alert("do something.........");
};
```